# Learning C++ vectors... Am I doing this correctly? Can my repeated calls to vector::push_back() be simplified?

Tags: c++, stdvector

First let me say this program is in no way meant to be useful. This is just me writing something to test and learn how to use vectors.

In this example, I am employing several actions that I would need to do in a real life project I'm working on. I had to figure out how to do a lot of this from about 20 different examples found on Google.

This is the first time I've ever done anything with vectors and **I want to make sure that everything I'm doing is safe**. **I also want to know if my repeated calls to `vector::push_back()` could be simplified?** Please note that the code *does* work as I am intending it to. I am just looking to see if I'm overlooking anything, misunderstanding anything, making unsafe calls, etc.

Last thing... **I'm also wanting to learn how to use smart pointers (`auto_ptr`). But so far, I don't see that it would benefit this example?**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;
typedef vector<unsigned char> message;


void append_file( message& buffer, int header_size )
{

    ifstream is("vector",ifstream::binary);
    is.seekg(0,ios::end);
    int length = is.tellg();
    is.seekg(0, ios::beg);

    buffer.reserve( header_size + length );
    buffer.resize( header_size +length );

    is.read( (char*)&buffer[header_size], length );
    is.close();

    buffer.at(4) = (buffer.size() & 0xFF00) >> 8;
    buffer.at(5) = buffer.size() & 0xFF;

}

int main( int argc, char *argv[] )
{

    while( true ) //this is just for me to watch memory usage
    {
        message msg;

        msg.push_back(0x00);
        msg.push_back(0x00);
        msg.push_back(0x01);
        msg.push_back(0x82);
        msg.push_back(0x00);
        msg.push_back(0x06);

        msg.push_back(0x01);
        msg.push_back(0x01);
        msg.push_back(0x20);
        msg.push_back(0x01);
        msg.push_back(0x25);
        msg.push_back(0x04);

        int header = msg.size();

        append_file( msg, header );

        ofstream os("test.dt",ofstream::binary);
        os.write( (char*)&msg[0], msg.size() );
        os.close();

        cout << "Wrote " << msg.size() << " bytes" << endl;

        cout << "Press any key to repeat...";
        cin.get();

    } //it is my understanding from my reading on vectors that the memory will be de-allocated here. Is this correct? It seems to be? At least on Linux.

    return 0;

}
```

## Note: Please do **not** mention boost, MFC, or ATL.

Comment: Whatever you do, don't try to use `auto_ptr` in standard containers. It just won't work.

Comment: I also played around with `reserve()`, but was more satisfied with the usage of `resize()`. Speed is not too *critical* in my real-life application, but the program will be running 24/7 on a PC that already has a 100 process running, so memory usage is a big factor.

Comment: Listen to @R.MartinhoFernandes - basically never store an auto_ptr in a container - so many many things go wrong ;-)

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes, Can you elaborate more on why it would not work? I'm not 100% clear on what you're referring to by "standard containers." Would these [examples](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Auto_ptr) fall under the scope of that?

Comment: Standard containers are `std::vector`, `std::list`, all those things. A vector of auto_ptrs (`std::vector<std::auto_ptr<T>>`) does not behave correctly because `auto_ptr` has some strange copy semantics. It works fine (if you're careful) outside containers, but inside them, it doesn't. You can find smart pointers that you can use in standard containers in C++11 (unique_ptr and shared_ptr) and in boost (yeah, I know you said not to mention it, but if your compiler doesn't support some C++11, it's your best bet :).

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes, what about smart pointers to a std container? e.g. `auto_ptr< vector< char > >` ? If I were to implement smart pointers, this is what I would be doing.

Comment: @druciferre If you are reusing the vector remember to use the swap() trick. Because if you insert a million elements into a vector and then resize to 10 - you vector will still have memory allocated for a million elements. Create a new vector of 10 and use the swap - to switch the storage - this way when million reserved element vector will get destroyed

Comment: @druciferre an auto_ptr to a vector is cool - a vector of auto_ptr is bad :-)

Comment: @AdrianCornish, That is an example of exactly why I posted this question. In my real-life application I actually would be re-using the vector.

Comment: I shall update my answer to include code for the swap trick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way to simplify:

```
message m;
std::back_insert_iterator<message> i(m);

i = 0x00;
i = 0x00;
i = 0x01;
i = 0x82;
i = 0x00;
i = 0x06;

i = 0x01;
i = 0x01;
i = 0x20;
i = 0x01;
i = 0x25;
i = 0x04;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify initializing `msg` with:

```
#include <algorithm>

message msg(10);
std::copy_n("\x00\x00\x01\x82\x00\x06\x01\x01\x20\x01\x25\x04", msg, 10);
```

Answer (score 1):

> I also want to know if my repeated calls to vector::push_back() could be simplified?

Not much. In C++11, you can initialize the vector with the list of elements (`message msg = {0x00, 0x00, 0x01.....}`, but that requires the compiler to support this feature, and it's quite likely that your compiler doesn't yet support it.

> Last thing... I'm also wanting to learn how to use smart pointers (auto_ptr). But so far, I don't see that it would benefit this example?

You're right. The magic word is RAII: Resource Acquisition is Initialization. What it means is that resources should be owned by C++ objects, which take care of acquiring and releasing the resources. A smart pointer is one way to do this (you have a pointer to some heap-allocated memory, and you wrap it in a smart pointer, which takes care of releasing the memory when it is time), but `std::vector` (or the other standard library containers also implement RAII semantics. They own the objects placed in them, and they take care of releasing them when they need to be released.

Your own home-built objects can also do the same. Smart pointers are nothing special in this respect, they're just a convenient shortcut for RAII'ifying raw pointers. But there are many other ways to make your resources use RAII.

(One of my pet peeves is that many people seem to think that smart pointers (and specifically `shared_ptr`) are all that RAII is about: that if you want to avoid memory leaks, you need to put *everything* in a `shared_ptr`. That's not true. All that matters is that your objects are designed with clear ownership semantics, so that it is always clear which object owns a resource (a resource might be a memory allocation, a file handle, a window, a network socket or anything else that needs to be acquired and released), and so that the owner will take care of releasing the owned resource. Smart pointers are just  premade classes that behave like this.

About `auto_ptr`, stay far away from it. It's not very useful. It can not be safely stored in the `std` containers, and it has some quirky behavior, which is why it is deprecated in C++11.

Instead, use the "new" generation of smart pointers: `shared_ptr` (if you want shared ownership), `scoped_ptr` (if you want exclusive, non-transferable ownership tied to a single scope), or `unique_ptr` for something that behaves like an `auto_ptr` but which *works*.

The first two are in Boost (which you should use in any case) and TR1 (which probably comes with your compiler), and all three are in the C++11 standard library.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a better way to initialize your message:

```
static const char header[] = { '\x00', '\x00', '\x01', '\x82', '\x00',
                               '\x06', '\x01', '\x01', '\x20', '\x01',
                               '\x25', '\x04' };
vector<char> msg(header, header + (sizeof(header) / sizeof(header[0])));
```

In C++11 you could, of course, do this:

```
vector<char> msg { '\x00', '\x00', '\x01', '\x82', '\x00', '\x06',
                   '\x01', '\x01', '\x20', '\x01', '\x25', '\x04' };
```

As for the `swap` trick mentioned elsewhere... I don't think it's a good idea. Unless your buffer sometimes has absolutely huge messages and then goes back to having relatively small messages you lose more than you gain with the `swap` trick. You don't want to have the underlying vector be allocating memory all the time, and swapping with a new empty vector forces exactly that to happen.

BTW, the constructor call can be replaced with a call to `assign` when you re-use the vector, like so:

```
 msg.assign(header, header + (sizeof(header) / sizeof(header[0]));
```

Also, there is a problem with your code. You are not verifying that the file size will fit into a 16 bit value. This means if you try to send a file that's too big for the size field in your message you will have a broken size field. This is particularly vexing since you send the entire file regardless of what's in the size field. This means the contents of the file may be interpreted as the header for the next message in some circumstances.

Fortunately (though I expect rather accidentally) your use of `tellg`, `resize`, and `read` do conspire to ensure that you will crash from an out-of-memory exception rather than have a buffer overrun if your file is too big to fit into an in-memory buffer. Though there is the possibility of negative underrun if your file size is greater than 2G. I won't hazard a guess as to what wil happen if that occurs. `length` should probably not be an integer. Figure out what type `tellg` is supposed to give you and use that instead.

Answer (score 0):

Yes they could be with boost libraries assign ([boost assign](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/assign/doc/index.html)) extras or in C++11 they made it smarter too.

Overall you do not need to mix reserve and resize. You should choose which works best for you. reserve() guarantees that you can allocate that many items without the vector reallocating space. resize() means the memory is already allocated and you are allowed to write to it.

Also remember by the standard a vector is never required to give back the memory it has allocated. So for example if your vector grows to a million elements and there after you only need 10 - the vector shall hold system memory for the ability to store million elements. This can be fixed by the swap() trick

```
std::vector<int> foo(100000);

std::vector<int> small(10);

foo.swap(small); // now when small goes out of scope the 1,000,000 mem allocated
                 // vector shall be freed;
```

Comment: I think you reversed the operations of `reserve()` and `resize()`.

Comment: trust me I did not. v.reserve(10) - mean v[5] will core dump - where as v.resize(10) shall not.

Comment: Is it possible to do this `is.read( (char*)&buffer[header_size], length );` when using `reserve()` instead of `resize()` ? I have to be able to do that in my real-world application as I'm working with Windows API calls like `WriteFile()` and `ReadFile()`. From what I've read so far, it sounds like if I used `reserve()` I would need to explicitly use `vector::push_back()`.

Comment: absolutely not - reserve only require that the vector shall not be moved so that iterators are valid. resize requires that that the mem is available and reserved from the the OS.

Comment: When I do that with `vector::reserve()`, the `vector::size()` doesn't seem to update. I have to call `vector::resize()` before it will update. You said I should not mix both, so how do I insure the `vector::size()` is accurate when writing to `&buffer[header_size]` ?

Comment: @druciferre Don't assign to specific elements after a call to `reserve` it means the vector internally reserves memory, it doesn't mean you are allowed to access it. A crucial difference between `reserve` and `resize` is also the call to the default ctor, which introduces overhead if that's not what you want.